# Install program from tar.bz2

Tags: 12.04, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)

Could someone explain to me in the simplest way possible how to install a program from a .tar.bz2 file? I've looked this up and went through numerous tutorials but couldn't get it to work at all. Most replies to this question seem to be incomplete or intended for more advanced users.

Let's say the file is located at `/home/user/file.tar.bz2`

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

**Edit**

I ran the command Rinzwind suggested and then opened the directory it created in the terminal. Next I ran `./configure` and I got the following message when it finished.

```
checking for BABL... no
configure: error: Package requirements (babl >= 0.1.10) were not met:

No package 'babl' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BABL_CFLAGS
and BABL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details
```

What happened?

**Edit 2**

Rinzwind: Everything with babl went seemingly okay but I had a problem with gegl:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.28.0... no
*** Could not run GLIB test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GLIB is incorrectly installed.
configure: error: 
*** GLIB 2.28.0 or better is required. The latest version of
*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/.
```

I took a guess (probably a bad idea) and did the following:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/glib/2.32/glib-2.32.1.tar.xz
tar -xvf glib-2.32.1.tar.xz
cd glib-2.32.1
./configure
```

But then I got this error

```
checking for inflate in -lz... no
configure: error: *** Working zlib library and headers not found ***
```

What happened?